# I am trying to create a Token on the Ethereum Blockchain but it is giving me a "ReferenceError" every time I run the code

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, referenceerror

Here is my Code:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const hre = require("hardhat");

describe("JaiToken contract", function() {

    let Token;
    let jaiToken;
    let owner;
    let addr1;
    let addr2;
    let tokenCap = 50000000;
    let tokenBlockReward = 20;

    beforeEach(async function () {

        Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("JaiToken");
        [owner, addr1, addr2] = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

        jaiToken = await Token.deploy(tokenCap, tokenBlockReward);
    });

    describe("Deployment", function () {
        it("Should set the right owner", async function () {
          expect(await jaiToken.owner()).to.equal(owner.address);
        });
     
        it("Should assign the total supply of tokens to the owner", async function () {
          const ownerBalance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
          expect(await jaiToken.totalSupply()).to.equal(ownerBalance);
        });
    
        it("Should set the max capped supply to the argument provided during deployment", async function () {
          const cap = await jaiToken.cap();
          expect(Number(hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(cap))).to.equal(tokenCap);
        });
    
        it("Should set the blockReward to the argument provided during deployment", async function () {
          const blockReward = await jaiToken.blockReward();
          expect(Number(hre.ethers.utils.formatEther(blockReward))).to.equal(tokenBlockReward);
        });
      });

      describe("Transactions", function () {
        it("Should transfer tokens between accounts", async function () {
          // Transfer 50 tokens from owner to addr1
          await jaiToken.transfer(addr1.address, 50);
          const addr1Balance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(addr1.address);
          expect(addr1Balance).to.equal(50);

          // Transfer 50 tokens from addr1 to addr2
          // We use .connect(signer) to send a transaction from another account
          await jaiToken.connect(addr1).transfer(addr2.address, 50);
          const addr2Balance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(addr2.address);
          expect(addr2Balance).to.equal(50);
        });

        it("Should fail if sender doesn't have enough tokens", async function () {
          const initialOwnerBalance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
          // Try to send 1 token from addr1 (0 tokens) to owner (1000000 tokens).
          // `require` will evaluate false and revert the transaction.
          await expect(
            jaiToken.connect(addr1).transfer(owner.address, 1)
          ).to.be.revertedWith("ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");

          // Owner balance shouldn't have changed.
          expect(await jaiToken.balanceOf(owner.address)).to.equal(
            initialOwnerBalance
          );
        });

        it("Should update balances after transfers", async function () {
          const initialOwnerBalance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(owner.address);

          // Transfer 100 tokens from owner to addr1.
          await jaiToken.transfer(addr1.address, 100);

          // Transfer another 50 tokens from owner to addr2.
          await jaiToken.transfer(addr2.address, 50);

          // Check balances.
          const finalOwnerBalance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(owner.address);
          expect(finalOwnerBalance).to.equal(initialOwnerBalance.sub(150));

          const addr1Balance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(addr1.address);
          expect(addr1Balance).to.equal(100);

          const addr2Balance = await jaiToken.balanceOf(addr2.address);
          expect(addr2Balance).to.equal(50);
      });
    });

  });
```

Here is my Error:

```
describe("JaiToken contract", function() {
^

ReferenceError: describe is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/owner/Desktop/HTML/JaiToken/Jai-Token/test/JaiToken.js:4:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

Node.js v17.4.0
```

I was expecting that all 7 tests ran will be passed in the Terminal and check out, instead it throws the Describe Error. I looked through my code multiple times and researched on this error but cannot find out what is wrong. I am using VS Code as my editor or maybe I did not download the right things. This contract is used to apply functionality to my Tokens such as setting the Balance, Cap, making sure it is the Owner, and setting the Block Reward for whom who adds the transaction on the Blockchain. I also have already checked that this file is in the Test file and that these are all test I am running. Please Help!

Comment: you either do  not have mocha or chai installed. Or, test directory is not in top level where package.json is

Comment: What do you mean by test directory is not in top level where package.json is? I already have mocha and chai installed.